# my variable didn't recognize in other PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

Hello I created a exporter page that when user filter data and press filter... data appear down below of table and then user can export the data that filter but there is a problem while exporting and here is the ERROR IMAGE that printed in to exported CSV file:

[image]

it exported when I press the export BTN.

but Here is the Problem Area:

```
<?php

    include('database_connection.php');
$query='';
if(isset($_POST["export_rule"]))  
 {  
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "uni");  
      header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=EXPORT_FILTER.csv');  
      $output = fopen("php://output", "w");  
    /////////////////
    
       fputcsv($output, array('email', 'password', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'field', 'country'));
$tag= $_POST['tags'];
    $field=$_POST['filter_field'];
        $country=$_POST['filter_country'];
  
   //   $search = str_replace(",", "|",$all );
    
 $query .= '
 SELECT * FROM csv WHERE email LIKE "%'.$tag.'%" AND field = "'.$field.'" AND Country = "'.$country.'" 
 ';


  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
      {
           fputcsv($output, $row);
          
      }   
      fclose($output);  
   
 }

 ?>
```

at this part

```
$tag= $_POST['tags'];
        $field=$_POST['filter_field'];
            $country=$_POST['filter_country'];
```

i use variable that user filtered in index page

and here is my index page:

```
<?php

include('database_connection.php');




//index.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=uni", "root", "");

$qy = "SELECT DISTINCT email FROM csv ORDER BY email ASC";

$sta = $connect->prepare($qy);

$sta->execute();

$resa = $sta->fetchAll();




$country='';
$field='';
$qu = "SELECT DISTINCT field FROM csv ORDER BY field ASC";
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM csv ORDER BY Country ASC";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row)
{
 $country .= '<option value="'.$row['Country'].'">'.$row['Country'].'</option>';
}
$field='';
$state = $connect->prepare($qu);
$state->execute();
$res = $state->fetchAll();
foreach($res as $row)
{
 $field .= '<option value="'.$row['field'].'">'.$row['field'].'</option>';
}


?>

<html>
 <head>
  <title> Search By at least 3 Rule</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <link href="css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
     
 </head>
 <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">upload by samad</a>
    </div>
   
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ><a href="index.php">search by company</a></li>
          <li class="active" ><a href="index_rule.php">Search by 2 Rule</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">tool box <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="https://extendsclass.com/csv-generator.html">CSV Generator</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/default.asp">W3 </a></li>
            <li><a href="https://gmail.com">check you're mail</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
          
        <li><a href="about.html">Who We Are</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="register.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  <div class="container box">
         <div class="container">
  <h3>search among of data that you stored them by check up 3 rule</h3>
  <p>HELP:you can  search anything BUT you need to check 3 availabe rule for this search for example you have to select field - country - and company to start searching so if you DONT fill All Data you will be alerted that you're leting a field empty and you must fill it too! </p>
</div>
      <br><br><br><br><br>
   <h1 align="center">Rule search </h1>
   <br />


      
      <br>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="form-group">
      <div align="center">
      
      
    
          </select>
      </div>
     </div>
        
        <form action="export_rule.php" method="post" class="form-group">
              <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
     <div  align="center" class="col-md-29">
      <input  type="text" name="tags" id="tags" placeholder="Company Filter" class="form-control"/>
     </div>
     
    </div>
   </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <select name="filter_field" id="filter_field" class="form-control" required>
       <option value="">Select Field</option>
       <?php echo $field; ?>
      </select>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <select name="filter_country" id="filter_country" class="form-control" required>
       <option value="">Select Country</option>
       <?php echo $country; ?>
      </select>
     </div>
            </form>
     <div class="form-group" align="center">
      <button type="button" name="filter" id="filter" class="btn btn-info">Filter</button>
         
     </div>
        
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="user_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th width="20%">Email</th>
       <th width="10%">Password</th>
       <th width="25%">FirstName</th>
       <th width="15%">LastName</th>
       <th width="15%">Field</th>
       <th width="15%">Country</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    </table>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
   </div>
  </div>
     <div align="center">
      <form action="export_rule.php" method="post"><input type="submit" name="export_rule" id="export_rule" value="CSV Export" class="btn btn-info" /> 
          </div>
 </body>
</html>
<?

///eport_rule
if(isset($_POST["export_rule"]))  
 {  
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "uni");  
      header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=EXPORT_FILTER.csv');  
      $output = fopen("php://output", "w");  
     
      fputcsv($output, array('email', 'password', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'field', 'country'));
 $sample= $_POST["tags"];
    $field=$_POST["filter_field"];
        $country=$_POST["filter_country"];
    $all=[$sample,$field,$country];
      $search = str_replace(",", "|",$all );
    
    
   $query .= '
 WHERE email LIKE "%'.$_POST['tags'].'%" AND field = "'.$_POST['filter_field'].'" AND Country = "'.$_POST['filter_country'].'" 
 ';
    
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
      {  
           fputcsv($output, $row);
          
      }   
      fclose($output);  
   
 }
?>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function(){
  
  fill_datatable();
  
  function fill_datatable(filter_field = '', filter_country = '', tags = '')
  {
   var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "order" : [],
    "searching" : false,
    "ajax" : {
     url:"fetch_rule.php",
     type:"POST",
     data:{
      filter_field:filter_field, filter_country:filter_country, tags:tags
     }
    }
   });
  }
  
        
  $('#filter').click(function(){
   var filter_field = $('#filter_field').val();
   var filter_country = $('#filter_country').val();
      var tags = $('#tags').val();
   if(filter_field != '' && filter_country != '' && tags != '')
   {
    $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
    fill_datatable(filter_field, filter_country, tags);
   }
   else
   {
    alert('you have to fill 3 option to search');
    $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
    fill_datatable();
   }
  });
     
 });

</script>
```

And for more intel here is the fetch.php that filter and receive data from DB:

```
<?php



////fetch_rule
include('database_connection.php');

$column = array('email', 'password', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'field', 'country');

$query = "
SELECT * FROM csv 
";


if(isset($_POST['filter_field'], $_POST['filter_country']) && $_POST['filter_field'] != '' && $_POST['filter_country'] != '' && $_POST['tags'] != '')
{
 $query .= '
 WHERE email LIKE "%'.$_POST['tags'].'%" AND field = "'.$_POST['filter_field'].'" AND Country = "'.$_POST['filter_country'].'" 
 ';
}

if(isset($_POST['order']))
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
}
else
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY email ASC ';
}

$query1 = '';

if($_POST["length"] != -1)
{
 $query1 = 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$number_filter_row = $statement->rowCount();

$statement = $connect->prepare($query . $query1);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();



$data = array();

foreach($result as $row)
{
 $sub_array = array();
 $sub_array[] = $row['email'];
 $sub_array[] = $row['password'];
 $sub_array[] = $row['firstname'];
 $sub_array[] = $row['lastname'];
 $sub_array[] = $row['field'];
 $sub_array[] = $row['country'];
 $data[] = $sub_array;
}

function count_all_data($connect)
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM csv";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 return $statement->rowCount();
}

$output = array(
 "draw"       =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
 "recordsTotal"   =>  count_all_data($connect),
 "recordsFiltered"  =>  $number_filter_row,
 "data"       =>  $data
);

echo json_encode($output);

//////




?>
```

thank in advance for reading...
Image Of browser :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you that your variable (`tags`, `filter_field`, `filter_country`) does not exist. This means that the variables in question do not exist at the point when you try to refer to them. Things to work on to ensure this is fixed.

## Is the file which defines those variables evaluated?

You should have the file containing the definition of those variables required/included. It's easy to test whether that's the case: just throw an error (not on prod, if possible) from the file that you assume to be already existent and another from the file you are trying to use it at the point where you try to use it. If the first error is thrown, then the file is evaluated at the point you try to use it. If not, then not.

## Are all the conditions met?

Try to throw an exception from the inside of the if. If it's thrown, then `export_rule` is set in `$_POST`.

## Are you sending the correct $_POST parameters?

Some of your items might be missing from `$_POST`. It is recommended to use defaults for the case when they do not exist. Your HTML looks to have some `form` tags without the items that you expect. You need to have some HTML tags with their `name` having the value of `tags`, `filter_field` and `filter_country` respectively inside the `form` tag. If you do not have that - and that looks to be the case - then that's a problem to fix for sure.

## Fix your HTML

Make sure you close your tags properly. Use an HTML validator (like this one: https://validator.w3.org/) to check what makes your HTML invalid and fix the issues.